# jquery css dynamic or static html elements

Tags: jquery

in my website i have to create dynamic elements.

some elements have lots of properties like: id, class, title, href for links etc...

i was looking at some example on different sites and i saw 2 different way i can build my code

**#1 static**

```
$('#mydivid').html('<a href="http://domain.com/page.html" title="my link" id="linkid" class="links-green">link</a>');
```

**#2 dynamic**

```
var anchor = $('<a />', {
  className: 'links-green',
  id: 'linkid',
  title: 'my link',
  href: 'http://domain.com/page.html',
  text: "linkk",
}).appendTo('#mydivid');
```

i would like to know this:

since the result is the same, which one is consider better to use as a coding standard?

Answer (score 1):

The second is better since you don't need to worry about properly escaping the values. For example if the values of the different attributes were dynamic and comping from variables, if you used the first example you would have to do string concatenations in order to format the value and then if there are some special characters inside those variables this could produce invalid markup.